# Reading database connection configuration from a registry properties file in WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

We are doing a POC in WSO2 EI and developing an API for service orchestration. As part of it, I want to insert some data into a database. In Integration Studio 8.0.0, I am using the DB report mediator to insert data. Everything works fine when I hardcode the values as shown in the below screenshot.
[image]

Now, I want to read the database configurations from a properties file I created in registry config folder instead of hardcoding them.  How can we achieve this?

Below is the screenshot of the registry properties file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't read properties files from the registry as key/value pairs and use them in integrations without processing the content of the properties file with something like the ScriptMediator. But you can pass a properties file to the runtime and pick the values from there. Please have a look at [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Injecting+Parameters+using+Configuration+Files) document.

Comment: In the document https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Injecting+Parameters+using+Configuration+Files, it's given the supported parameters are only Endpoint parameters, Scheduled Task parameters, Inbound Endpoint parameters, Proxy service parameters, Message Store parameters. So, don't think this approach will work for setting DB connection parameters.

Comment: Thanks, It's working for the DB connection parameters also. The doc. https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Injecting+Parameters+using+Configuration+Files can be updated to include database connection parameters as supported as well.

Answer (score 0):

We can inject DB connection parameters from a properties file stored in EI/MI product home folders but still need to find how we can inject parameters from registry.